# Cron tab runs multiple times

Tags: linux, cron

i have many crons running in the same time,
but just one of them runs multiple time (should be once an hour)
but it runs 10-12 times, and then stopes.

the logs look unussual like this:

```
Jul 14 11:01:02 ip-10-76-186-138 crond[829]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 14 11:04:02 ip-10-76-186-138 crontab[2971]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jul 14 11:05:00 ip-10-76-186-138 crontab[2971]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Jul 14 11:05:00 ip-10-76-186-138 crontab[2971]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Jul 14 11:05:01 ip-10-76-186-138 crond[1211]: (root) RELOAD (cron/root)
Jul 14 11:05:05 ip-10-76-186-138 crontab[3514]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jul 14 11:06:51 ip-10-76-186-138 crontab[3962]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jul 14 11:07:04 ip-10-76-186-138 crontab[3962]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Jul 14 11:07:04 ip-10-76-186-138 crontab[3962]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Jul 14 11:07:09 ip-10-76-186-138 crontab[4014]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jul 14 11:08:01 ip-10-76-186-138 crond[1211]: (root) RELOAD (cron/root)
Jul 14 11:10:01 ip-10-76-186-138 crond[4606]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

Comment: The log shows the crontab file being edited. There are two cron events but they are different jobs (cron.hourly and sa1) -- no duplicates.